# Query two tables and sum

Tags: mysql

How can I query two tables and sum the result. What I mean I have table

```
Job
-----
job_id
job_cost
```

And second table

```
worker
------
worker_id
worker_name
```

And here is the pivot table

```
finished_work
--------
job_id
worker_id
hours
```

So I want to sum all Hours from `finished_work` and based on `job_cost` to show total amount of all finished works. Example

```
work_1 - 40 hours * 5(job_cost) = 200
work_2 -3 hours * 15 = 45

total = 245
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you also post some sample data along with expected result set?

Comment: Sample data like: `John, 3 hours, Construction at 5 per hours`, `Peter, 5 hours, Car repair, 10 per hours`

Comment: So here John charge total of 15 and Peter total of 50. The query need to show me total from both i.e. `65`. Just can't figure out how to query and sum them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is with proc sql.  Here's an example where I use two pro sql statements to print out the intermediary file you might want.  If not you can just run the second sql query.

first we create your data sets:

```
data job;
job_id = 1;
job_cost = 5;
output;
job_id = 2;
job_cost = 10;
output;
run;

data worker;
worker_id = 1;
worker_name = 'Jon';
output;
worker_id = 2;
worker_name = 'Peter';
output;
run;

data finished;
job_id = 1;
worker_id = 1;
hours = 3;
output;
job_id = 2;
worker_id = 2;
hours = 5;
output;
run;
```

here's the intermediary sql file:

```
proc sql noprint;
create table projects as
       select a.worker_name,b.hours,c.job_cost,b.hours*c.job_cost as total
             from worker as a
       left join finished as b
           on a.worker_id = b.worker_id
       left join job as c
           on b.job_id = c.job_id;quit;
```

and here's the final answer all in one step:

```
proc sql noprint;
     create table project as
           select sum(total) as Grand_Total
                  from(select a.worker_name,b.hours,c.job_cost,b.hours*c.job_cost as total
                              from worker as a
                       left join finished as b
                            on a.worker_id = b.worker_id
                       left join job as c
                            on b.job_id = c.job_id);quit;
```

Sorry about the SAS - thought this was coming from a SAS question.  The sql statements are valid for mysql just delete the proc sql noprint line